# Responsive (stacking) issues in Android 4.2 native app

Tags: android, responsive-design

We've been using the same method to stack columns on mobile for a while now. Don't think it's anything unusual, and our Litmus tests have always come back fine across the board. Recently a client with an Android device (S4 mini running 4.2) complained that the layout was broken. The media queries were firing just fine, and the non-stacking parts of the email were behaving as intended, but the 3 columns we were trying to stack stubbornly refused to do so.Is anybody else having a similar issue?

I've made a greatly simplified bit of demo code to illustrate the issue.

The CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {

*[class].fl{float:left !important;}
*[class].wr{display:block !important;}
*[class].width320{width:320px !important;}
*[class].width300{width:300px !important;}
*[class].height20{height:20px !important;}
```

The HTML:

```
<table width="600" class="width300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="187" height="60" class="wr fl width300" bgcolor="#000000" style="background-color:#000000;"></td>
        <td width="20" class="wr fl width300 height20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="186" height="60" class="wr fl width300" bgcolor="#000000" style="background-color:#000000;"></td>
        <td width="20" class="wr fl width300 height20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="187" height="60" class="wr fl width300" bgcolor="#000000" style="background-color:#000000;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: are you using a table row to display of column of items ?

Comment: On mobile, yes. So on desktop this displays as three columns with 20px gutters between them. When the media query fires the container shrinks to 300px and the cells stack on top of each other. These Litmus results should show you what I mean: https://litmus.com/pub/2becc0a/screenshots